# Why is !0 a type in Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL)?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

In many MSIL listings, I have observed the following:

```
System.Nullable`1<!0> etc ...
```

or

```
class !0 etc ...
```

What's the meaning of `!0` in these circumstances?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

This is quirk of the decompiler you use to look at a .NET assembly.  It is the behavior of ildasm.exe, other ones like Reflector or ILSpy get this right.  The Microsoft programmer who wrote it took a shortcut, they generated a string from the IL that just displays the type argument the way it is encoded, without writing the *extra* code to lookup the type argument name in the metadata.

You need to read `!n` as the n-th type argument of the generic type.  Where !0 means "first type argument", !1 means "second type argument", etcetera.  For Nullable<>, you know that '!0` means 'T' from the MSDN article.

You may also encounter something like `!!T`.  Two exclamation marks indicate a type argument for a generic *method*.  This time, ildasm.exe *does* look up the type argument name instead of using `!!0`.  Why the programmer took the shortcut on generic types but not on generic methods is hard to reverse-engineer.  Ildasm is a pretty quirky program and is written in a C++ coding style that's very different from other C++ code in .NET.  Not as disciplined, non-zero odds that this was an intern's assignment :)

The `1 suffix on "Nullable" is a normal encoding for generic type names, it indicates the generic type has one type argument.  In other words, for Nullable<> you'll never see !1 being used.

So simply read `!0` as "T".  Or use a better decompiler.

Answer (score 35):

That is a generic type parameter.

They are positional.

Decompile some generic code to see how they are used (compare IL vs C#).

Comment: If I use TryRoslyn I don't get it... http://goo.gl/ZZKE38 I get `!T` and `!!T`, depending if the generic parameter is of the containing class or of the method... The same if I use ildasm

Comment: @xanatos Not always. I also see code like `ldfld class System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2<!0, !1> valuetype System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2/Enumerator<!TKey, !TValue>::dictionary` or `call instance void class System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2<!TKey, !TValue>::Insert(!0, !1, bool)`. The raw IL only uses the positional argument anyway, though - the `!TKey` is already an attempt to make the IL more readable. Maybe it doesn't always work well? The ECMA spec always uses the positional `!0`/`!00` as well.