# What the meaning of " (!0) " in ILNumerics Library?

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

What the meaning of " (!0) "  in ILNumerics just like this

```
return (!0)ILMathInternal.exp(this.m_mu);
```

and like this,

```
return 0.5 + (!0)ILMathInternal.log(this.m_sigma) + this.m_mu + (!0)ILMathInternal.log(ILMathInternal.sqrt(2.0 * ILMathInternal.pi));
```

Why we use this kind of expression---"(!0)" ?

Comment: Where have you found it? Google didn't find it.

Comment: I don't think this is related with C#. `!0` does not generate a type for explicit casting.

Comment: We'll need more context to help you.

Comment: Are you sure the ILNumerics source code is C# and not C++?

Comment: Unless you post your source for this code, this question is useless. The code you've posted here exists nowhere else on the web (according to everyone's favourite search engine)

Comment: @Abbondanza from a look at the library's website, the "Computing Engine" is indeed for .NET: C# and VB

Comment: @ardila, but the underlying source code that OP has posted here can still be C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(!0)` has no meaning, it is not valid C#

---

If I had to guess, which I do, I suspect the `(!0)` is how a decompiler has chosen to represent some IL code that has no C# representation.

Comment: But if the ILNumerics source is C# it somehow has to be valid C#, right? Maybe the operator `!` has been overloaded?

Comment: @Abbondanza, I suspect that this is more likely, an issue with decompilation. The `(!0)` being a representation of some IL operation which has no C# representation.

Comment: @Abbondanza It seems to be [Generic attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559861/why-is-0-a-type-in-microsoft-intermediate-language-msil)